# Use doPost with link

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I am working on a Java-Project with html/ftl and so on...

I have a ftl file with a list like this:

```html
<table id="availableHOs">
 <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Street</th>
  <th>Town</th>
  <th>Capacity</th>
 </tr>
 <#list availableOffers as ho>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="guestgui?action=selectHolidayOffer&amp;hid=${ho.id}" title="Make Booking">${ho.id}</a></td>
  <td>${ho.addressData.street}</td>
  <td>${ho.addressData.town}</td>
  <td>${ho.capacity}</td>
 </tr>
 </#list>
</table>
```

(That is a template which we got from the university.)
My problem is that the Link in the table (with the title "Make Booking" uses a GET and not a POST. Could somebody help me to change this to a POST?
I only have an example with a submit button and a form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="guestgui?action=projekteSuchenU">
```

But I dont know how I would use this in the table. 
In summary, I would like to have a table / list where I have a link for each line that works with POST

I am abolut new in this topic, so please sorry for my bad explanation!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add form instead tag 'a':

```
<table id="availableHOs">
        <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
        </tr>
        <#list availableOffers as ho>
        <tr>
                <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="guestgui?action=selectHolidayOffer&amp;hid=${ho.id}">
                                <input type="submit" value="${ho.id}"/>
                        </form>
                </td>
                <td>${ho.addressData.street}</td>
                <td>${ho.addressData.town}</td>
                <td>${ho.capacity}</td>
        </tr>
        </#list>
</table>
```